# Set all nodes in Confluence Documentation mode as expanded

Tags: confluence

We are using Confluence for documentation, in a documentation theme. When a user comes to the Wiki, I would like all the nodes to be expanded be default.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'd need to change how **pagetree** macro is used in the sidebar:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/21300/how-to-expand-page-tree-in-confluence-4-0-documentation-theme

Answer (score 1):

For example, to display 12 levels specify `{pagetree:startDepth=12}`.

To configure the documentation theme, uncheck "Page tree", then in the "Navigation" textbox, add
`{pagetree:startDepth=12}`.